# Make a matrix from a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this [image].

I want to create a matrix where it counts the number of times each student says true and false.

[image]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df2 = df.melt()
pd.crosstab(df2['variable'], df2['value'])
```

Output:

```
value     False  True
variable             
Student1      1     2
Student2      2     1
Student3      1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `stack` and `unstack` with counting values in between:

```
 out = df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack()
```

But an even simpler way is to simply count values:

```
out = df.sum().to_frame(name='T').assign(F=lambda x: len(df) - x)
```

Output:

```
          False  True
Student1      1     2
Student2      2     1
Student3      1     2
```

Comment: Thank you so much? What if I didn't want the labels on the side and top. Like, I just want the matrix [ [1, 2,] , [2, 1], [1, 2]]

Comment: @user then `out.to_numpy().tolist()` should do it.

Comment: @user or you could use `lst = df.sum().tolist(); list(map(list, zip(lst, [len(df)-x for x in lst])))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do `value_counts`

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).T
Out[205]: 
     F  T
St1  1  2
St2  2  1
St3  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
>>> df.melt().value_counts().unstack().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
          False  True
Student1      1     2
Student2      2     1
Student3      1     2
```